# ReactJS - setState does not update property

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a property of type object array in a React component. Using `setState` I am trying to modify this property. But assigning a new value to this property inside 
`setState` has no effect. Please find below my sample code.

```
export const Test = ({
  objectArray,
  changeState = function (newoOjectArray) {
    this.setState({objectArray: newoOjectArray});
    console.log(JSON.stringify(objectArray)); // Doesn't reflect changes. Prints old objectArray
  }
 }) => 
(
    <div>Some data</div>
)
```

Some user action will trigger a call to `changeState(newoOjectArray)`. I am calling `setState` inside `changeState` function.
 
After calling `setState` if I print the `objectArray` variable to console it still holds old value. 
How can I make `setState` assign a new value to `objectArray`.
 
Thanks

**EDIT**
I am aware that `setState` is asynchronus and update to property may reflect after a delay. 
But in case of example code above objectArray variable is never updated even after delay.
I have implemented `componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps)` method and it gets called but it always receives old objectArray.
So I don't think the issue is related to `setState` being asynchronous.

**EDIT2**
I have created an example app to demonstrate the issue I am facing. The example app runs fine locally and I can reproduce the issue.
But I am not being able to get the same example app code working in `codepen`. it's giving me some '`unexpected token`' errors.
But I hope looking at the code will help understand my issue better.
The code is based on existing application structure.
[Codepen example here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZxGgBK).

In the code I have a `Parent` and two children `Child1` and `Child2`.
In `Parent` I have a function `changeState` defined which I am passing to `Child1` as property.
And to `Child2` I am passing a '`name`' property from `Parent`.
Clicking on `'Change Name`' button in `Child1` triggers a call to `changeState` function of `Parent`.
Initial value of name in `Parent` is '`Robert`'. `changeState` is invoked from `Child1` with new name value of '`Tom`'. 
But in `changeState` function assigning new value to '`name`' using `setState` has no effect. I am calling a function to print the '`name`' 
after `setState` has completed but it prints old name value and NOT the new one assigned in `setState`.

Comment: `setState()` may be asynchronous. Try doing this : `this.setState({objectArray: newoOjectArray}, () => console.log(this.state.objectArray);`

Comment: @Weedoze I tried adding console.log the way you suggested. But it never gets called. And nothing is logged. But console.log after setState is called which prints the old value.

Comment: Then pleas provide a minimal, working example

Comment: @Weedoze Added codepen example. Also edited the question to explain the codepen code.

Comment: I'm not quite aware of the syntactic sugar being used here, but shouldn't the state be in the state property for setState to modify it? at least that's how it always work for me. you access the state with `this.state.prop`, set it in a class with `state = {prop: "string"}` and then use `setState({prop: "modified-string"})` to change it.